# Can I drop the ‘in’ in this sentence. If not, why?

Tags: grammaticality

Gaming disorder is a severe addiction •in• which a person places far too much importance on video games.

I know in which can define a place, but addiction?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence, **in** is being used as a preposition. Although it can be used to define a physical place, it can also be used in other ways.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in):

1. **a** —used as a function word to indicate inclusion, location, or
   position within limits · *in* the lake · wounded *in* the leg · *in*
   the summer
   **b** : INTO 1 · went *in* the house
2. —used as a function word to indicate means, medium, or
   instrumentality ·  written *in* pencil · bound *in* leather
3. **a** —used as a function word to indicate limitation, qualification, or
   circumstance · alike *in* some respects · left *in* a hurry
    **b** : INTO
   2a · broke *in* pieces
4. —used as a function word to indicate purpose · said *in* reply
5. —used as a function word to indicate the larger member of a ratio ·
   one *in* six is eligible

In your sentence, playing video games happen ***in*** *the context* of a particular addiction. The preposition does not need to refer to a physical place—and neither does **in which**.

> I continued reading the book **in which** a character had just died.
>   I'm talking about the speech **in which** a certain word was used.
>   What's the name of that game **in which** royal characters moves around a checkered board?
>   Red is the colour **in which** the letter was written.

**In which** can often can be replaced by **where**. (Although not always; the last example sentence could not have such a substitution made.)  Typically, **in which** is used in formal writing, while **where** is more common in casual speech.